# how to make main menu of a nav bar active(highlighted) after selecting submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap nav bar with main menus and some submenus. all I need to do is to make one of the main menu active(highlighted) after I click to select its submenu. For example, if I click to select "For Shippers", "HOW IT WORKS" should become active and highlighted. Right now I can only make the main menu active if I select it, but it does not work with submenu.  Probably it just needs javascript or Jquery addition to my code below, but I am not very familiar with Jquery; I appreciate any help:

```js
$(function() {
  // highlight the current nav
  $("#index a:contains('HOME')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#shippers a:contains('SHIPPERS')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#carriers a:contains('CARRIERS')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#carrier_signup a:contains('First Time User Sign Up')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#carrier_login a:contains('Current User Login')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#about a:contains('ABOUT US')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#contact a:contains('CONTACT US')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#howitworks a:contains('HOW IT WORKS')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#hiw_shippers a:contains('FOR SHIPPERS')").parent().addClass('active');
  $("#hiw_carriers a:contains('FOR CARRIERS')").parent().addClass('active');

  // make menus drop automatically with hover for dropdown menu
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
  });
})
```

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #0064ff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-bar {
  margin: -20px 0px -20px 3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;America<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>Shipping Choice
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="Shippers_login.php">SHIPPERS</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Carriers.php">CARRIERS</a></li>-->

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CARRIERS
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="carrier_signup.php">First Time User <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href="carrier_login.php">Current User <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>

        <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">HOW IT WORKS
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="howitworks_shippers.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> For Shippers</a></li>
            <li><a href="howitworks_carriers.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> For Carriers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to highlight when hover or click? Because, if `on click` I don't see any point to highlight its parent. It will go to other page already.

But if on hover. You can add this to your CSS.

```
li:hover > a {background-color: #E8E8E8;}
li:hover a:hover {background-color: #E8E8E8;}
```

@

Add this to your JAVASCRIPT if you want `on click`

```
$(".dropdown-menu > li > a").on("click",function(x){
    var tgt     = $(this).closest(".dropdown").children("a");
    if(!tgt.hasClass("active"))
        tgt.addClass("active");
  x.preventDefault();
});

$("li").on("mouseover",function(){
    var tgt     = $(this).children("a");
    if(tgt.hasClass("active"))
        tgt.removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Your css on hover works, Thanks, but I actually want to highlight parent after the child is selected(or clicked) even though it already went to another page.

Comment: In my html code for example, I want to highlight parent "HOW IT WORKS" after the child "For Shippers" has been selected and moved to the child page. I tried your javascript but it does not work for this case.

Comment: All I need to do is to highlight parent when I am on child page- Just to clarify.

Comment: I apologize for my question because it may not work due to my parent page is not in existence. I will try to create a page for the parent instead of just href="#" to see if it will work. You can ignore my question for now. Thanks